# How to return an instance of a class in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, class, ios4

I'm trying to return an instance of a class in a function, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I have a class called GenerateMoves, and an instance of that class is created:

```
GenerateMoves *move = [[GenerateMoves alloc] init];
```

I then have another class which has to use the variables which are set up in that instance of the class ("move", from above).

So I created a function:

```
-(Class)returnClass {
return move;
}
```

And then in the other class:

```
GenerateMoves *move = [otherClass returnClass];
```

However, it throws a warning saying it is an incompatible pointer type.

How do I do this?

Thanks for your assistance! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want this:

```
-(GenerateMoves*)returnClass {
  return move;
}
```

Although I would call it returnMove, rather than returnClass

EDIT: A bit more detail.

While your way of writing things is perfectly valid Objective C, I think it's easier to understand if you write it like this:

```
GenerateMoves* move = [[GenerateMoves alloc] init];
```

in other words, you're creating a pointer to a GenerateMoves instance and assigning it to the variable move. It then follows naturally that the return type of returnClass is GenerateMoves* (again a pointer to a GenerateMoves instance)

Comment: Thank for your help! These are some great tips!